# Find a connected graph $G$ which is isomorphic to its line graph.

Tags: graph-theory

Find a connected graph $G$ with $n, (n \ge 3 )$ nodes with the property:

$$G \cong L(G)$$

My try:

The complete graph with 3 nodes ($K_3$) seems like a good candidate for this problem but I don't know how to prove it formally.

Comment: just construct it. Take $\phi : E_{K_3}\longrightarrow V_{K_3}$ enumerate all of them and see that it's a bijection and respects the connections.

Comment: The complete graph $K_3$ satisfies $K_3\cong L(K_3)$ but clearly this doesn't hold in general for $K_n$. In general it holds for the cycle graph $C_n$ that $C_n\cong L(C_n)$ and in your case $C_3=K_3$. It might be the case that $G\cong L(G)\iff G=C_n$ for some $n$, but I'm not sure how you'd prove the forward implication. The backwards implication, which is what you're asking for, should be reasonably easy to prove by just constructing the line graph explicitly.

Comment: @SiddharthPrasad But how do I prove it?

Comment: What is confusing you? Just figure out what $L(K_3)$ is based on the definition of line graph.

Comment: @SiddharthPrasad I thought it had to be harder than just drawing $K_3$ and $L(K_3)$.

Comment: I have asked this question when I needed clarification for a homework, but I got the full solution. If this questions stays here other students will come and copy it, it is a case of academic fraud.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a (finite simple) graph satisfying the condition $L(G)\cong G.$ Suppose $G$ has $n$ vertices, and let's try to figure out what its degree sequence $d_1,d_2,\dots,d_n$ can be.

Since $L(L(G))\cong L(G)\cong G,$ the three graphs $G,L(G),L(L(G))$ all have the same number of vertices, i.e., both $G$ and $L(G)$ have $n$ edges.

The number of edges in $G$ is $\frac12\sum_{i=1}^nd_1,$ and the number of edges in $L(G)$ is $\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{d_i}2,$ so we have
$$n=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^nd_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{d_i}2.$$
It follows from these equations that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(d_i-2)^2=0,$$
i.e.,
$$d_1=d_2=\cdots=d_n=2.$$
To see this, instead of doing the algebra directly, let's recast it in terms of probability. Let the random variable $X$ be the degree of a randomly chosen vertex of $G.$ Then the average degree of $G$ is
$$\mu=E[X]=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nd_i=2,$$
and
$$E\left[\binom X2\right]=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{d_i}2=1,$$
i.e.,
$$1=E\left[\binom X2\right]=E\left[\frac{X^2-X}2\right]=\frac12E\left[X^2\right]-\frac12E[X],$$
so
$$E\left[X^2\right]=E[X]+2=4=\mu^2$$
and
$$\text{Var}(X)=E\left[(X-\mu)^2\right]=E\left[X^2\right]-\mu^2=0.$$

We have shown that a graph which is isomorphic to its line graph must be $2$-regular; conversely, a
$2$-regular graph is a sum of cycles, which is clearly isomorphic to its line graph. Thus, the solutions of $L(G)\cong G$ are just the $2$-regular graphs, and the connected solutions are just the cycles.

Answer (score 1):

For any $n\geq3$ consider the cycle graph $C_n$. If you want to build a specific bijection between $C_n$ and $\operatorname{L}(C_n)$, then just temporarily impose a direction on the edges in $C_n$ such that each vertex has out-degree one (all edges point the same way), and have each vertex of $C_n$ map to the vertex of $\operatorname{L}(C_n)$ that corresponds to edge leaving it. Explaining why this is an isomorphism is tedious, but not difficult.