# Graph theory proof if L(G)=G then G is a combination of simple cycles.

Tags: graph-theory

I need to prove in graph theory that if L(G)=G then G is a combination if simple cycles.
I already did it assuming G is connected, so feel free to use this fact as given.

My only issue is that it may be possible that in a non-connected graph not every one of the connected components will satisfy L(G)=G.
For example, if the Connected components in G are A,B,C it may be possible that
L(A)=B, L(B)=C, L(C)=A.

Comment: Maybe you can prove that a cycle of line graphs can't occur? Maybe you can prove that, if $A$ is a connected graph which is not a path graph or a cycle graph, then the graphs L(A), L(L(A)), L(L(L(A))), . . . just keep getting bigger and bigger?

Comment: By the way, the accepted solution of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004211/find-a-connected-graph-g-which-is-isomorphic-to-its-line-graph) contains a proof that any (finite simple) graph $G$ such that $L(G)\cong G$ is $2$-regular (*i.e.* it's a sum of vertex-disjoint cycles), and there is no mention of connectedness.

Comment: @bof I have seen the proof that you sent and I couldn't understand how they got to this sum of squares from the equations they written above. because to get (di-2)^2 there needs to be a +4 somewhere and I can figure out where it is.

Comment: Edit: After some Algebra I understood, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, which eliminates your issue. Let $c(G)$ be the number of cycles in the graph $G$.

Claim: $c(L(G)) \geq c(G)$, and $c(L(G)) > c(G)$ if there is a vertex of degree at least $3$ in $G$.

Proof: every cycle in $G$ becomes a cycle in $L(G)$. If there is a vertex of degree at least $3$ in $G$, then the edges incident to this vertex create a clique, and hence a cycle, which does not come from a cycle of $G$.

How does this help? Well, if $L(G) = G$, then the maximum degree of $G$ is at most $2$, so $G$ is a disjoint union of paths and cycles. We can eliminate the paths either by hand (the longest path could not exist, since paths shrink when moving to the line graph), or by noting that the number of edges of $G$ equals the number of vertices of $G$ if $L(G) = G$.